# onmousedown hide/show div

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function that hides/shows a div when clicking on a button. The idea would be to be able to pass the ID of the div I want to hide through the event. But I'm not quite sure how to do it.

This is what I have done until now:

```
<div onmousedown="toogleDiv(badges)"> //clicking here should hide div id=badges
Icons v
</div>

<div id="badges">
</div>

<div onmousedown="toogleDiv(items)"> //clicking here should hide div id=items
Items v
</div>
<div id="items">
</div>

<script>
// Hide/show div;
function toogleDiv()
{
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try jquery, if you are new to javascript.

Comment: I have to disagree and recommend learning real Javascript, jQuery has become too popular amongst newbies and has prevented then to learn how to code correctly, understand the DOM and follow good programming practices. It just spoils lazy people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toogleDiv(id){
    var s = document.getElementById(id).style;
    s.display = s.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Then you can pass the id in as a string IE instead of `toggleDiv(items)` use `toggleDiv('items')`

[***Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/Ya6RN/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function hideDiv(id) 
{ 
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
}
```